# handlebarsjs - Can I access element by json key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I have json like this:

```
"elements":[

{
"type":"AAAA",
"val":{"detail":"111"}},

"type":"BBBB",
"val":{"detail":"222"}}
}]
```

How can I get value `detail` for element with specific type?
I can probably make a each loop, but is there any more efficient way, like in XSL:

```
{{elements.type['AAAA'].val}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain Javascript, you can write a helper function for it.

```js
function getReference(array, key) {
    var r;
    array.some(function (a) {
        if (a.type === key) {
            r = a;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return r;
}

var object = { "elements": [{ "type": "AAAA", "val": { "detail": "111" } }, { "type": "BBBB", "val": { "detail": "222" } }] };

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getReference(object.elements, 'AAAA').val, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: this looks perfect. 
However ... There may be additional challenge if our array is not on the top level, adn we need to access top level data and array.
Example:


var object = { "someheader":"header title", {"elements": [{ "type": "AAAA", "val": { "detail": "111" } }, { "type": "BBBB", "val": { "detail": "222" } }]} };


Is there any way to pass whole object to handlebars and have also access to array?

Comment: @plusz, i must state, i do not have **any** clue of javascript frameworks or tools. i do all without.